# Arrow keys on bluetooth keyboard produce punctuation characters

Tags: lumia, bluetooth, keyboard

I've successfully paired by bluetooth keyboard with my Microsoft Lumia 640 and it works great - mostly.

The letters, digits and Enter key all work as expected, but the arrow keys are behaving very oddly.

The <kbd>▲</kbd> key goes up and then types <kbd>&</kbd>.
The <kbd>▼</kbd> key goes down and then types a <kbd>(</kbd>.
The <kbd>◀</kbd> key inserts a <kbd>%</kbd> and then goes left.
The <kbd>▶</kbd> key inserts a <kbd>'</kbd> and then goes right.
(I wish I were joking.)

The same keyboard works fine, including arrow keys, with my Acer Iconia tablet running Windows 8.1.

Please, what's going on? Many thanks.

Update: OS versions as requested...
[image: OS Versions of my Lumia 640]

Comment: What OS and firmware versions are you running on your 640?

Comment: @CBHacking - Edited question. Many thanks.